# Java code to convert between UTF8 and UTF16 offsets (Java string offsets to/from Python 3 string offsets)

Tags: java, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, utf-16

Given a Java string and an offset into that String, what is the correct way of calculating the offset of that same location into an UTF8 string?

More specifically, given the offset of a valid codepoint in the Java string, how can one map that offset to a new offset of that codepoint in a Python 3 string? And vice versa?

Is there any library method which already provides the mapping between Java String offsets and Python 3 string offsets?

Comment: A naive way would be to take the substring before that offset, convert it to UTF-8, and count the bytes.

Comment: Joshm is asking for a codepoint index, not a byte index.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way in Java is to use [codePointCount](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointCount-int-int-):

```
String sample = " - abc";
int javaIndex = sample.indexOf("abc");
int codePointIndex = sample.codePointCount(0, javaIndex);

System.out.println(javaIndex);
System.out.println(codePointIndex);
```

Output:

```
5
4
```

While Java's UTF-16 format is a variable length format and requires two `char`s for the emoji, it's just a single codepoint according to the Unicode standard. So the Java index for `abc` is 5 but the codepoint index (also applicable to Python 3 strings) is 4.

Note that the Java method needs to *count* the codepoints one by one as the name of the method implies. So it's not a closed mathematical formula.

Answer (score 0):

No, there cannot be. UTF-16 uses a varying number of code units per codepoint and so does UTF-8. So, the indices are entirely dependent on the codepoints in the string. You have to scan the string and count.

There are relationships between the encodings, though. A codepoint has two UTF-16 code units if and only if it has four UTF-8 code units. So, an algorithm could tally UTF-8 code units by scanning UTF-16 codepoints: 4 four a high surrogate, 0 for a low surrogate, 3 for some range, 2 for another and 1 for another.

Comment: What I mean is that it must be possible to map all offsets into a Java string which point to a valid code point to offsets into a Python string and back. As far as I understand this can be done by looking at the code point indices (as explained by @Codo on the Java side) but I would be interested in some library code that does this rather than programming it myself (there may be details or traps I am not aware of).